# Mysql select by auto increment primary key while partitioned by date

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, database-partitioning

I was wondering how would mysql act if i partition a table by *date* and then have some *select* or *update* queries by *primary key* ?

is it going to search all partitions or query optimizer knows in which partition the row is saved ?

What about other unique and not-unique indexed columns ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Background**

Think of a `PARTITIONed` table as a collection of virtually independent tables, each with its own data BTree and index BTree(s).

All `UNIQUE` keys, including the `PRIMARY KEY` must include the "partition key".

If the partition key is available in the query, the query will first try to do "partition pruning" to limit the number of partitions to actually look at.  Without that info, it must look at all partitions.

After the "pruning", the processing goes to each of the possible partitions, and performs the query.

**Select, Update**

A `SELECT` logically does a `UNION ALL` of whatever was found in the non-pruned partitions.

An `UPDATE` applies its action to each non-pruned partitions.  No harm is done (except performance) by the updates that did nothing.

**Opinion**

In my experience, `PARTITIONing` often slows thing down due to things such as the above.  There are a small number of use cases for partitioning:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

**Your specific questions**

> partition a table by date and then have some select or update queries by primary key ?

All partitions will be touched.  The `SELECT` combines the one result with N-1 empty results.  The `UPDATE` will do one update, plus N-1 useless attempts to update.

An `AUTO_INCREMENT` column must be the first column in *some* index (not necessarily the PK, not necessarily alone).  So, using the id is quite efficient *in each partition*.  But that means that it is N times as much effort as in a non-partitioned table.  (This is a performance *drag* for partitioning.)